Trying to add a CC to an email script for Google Sheets that comes from a column in the sheet
This is for a restaurant group with multiple locations that does catering. The script was done by someone else. It works ok in that in the email recipient row I can add a static list of 4 people who need to get the email but I can not figure out how to add a CC so that the specific location for which the event is for also gets the email. It is a very simple set-up - Google form linked to a Google sheet and the script is part of the Google sheet. When the form is submitted a new row is populated in the sheet, the script runs and the email goes out. The CC address would come from the row of data (specifically a column and each new row could have a different location email) in the Google sheet. In the script section HTML body you can see it is pulling the data from the sheet, identifying each piece by a row number (it is a standard spreadsheet with the data in columns from left to right but the script specifics ROWS which to me implies vertically but it works).
I can get it to work by adding a CC in a manner similar to recipients, and adding a CC two lines below mail app but then it is a static CC and not looking to the sheet to get the location specific address for that new event.
Various examples from web searches on how to add this function but the examples have scripts that use very different set-ups so none seem to apply to how this script was written.
Image of Current Script

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Assuming you set a variable ccList with the cc email, add cc: to sendEmail
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailDistro, subject, body, {
      cc: ccList,
      noReply: true,
      htmlBody: body
    }

